# How to protect my Node.JS source code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've found some solutions such as: `Enclose.JS` and `Nexe`. They compile files into an executable file.

But in my situation, I want to keep some files without compiling for user config, and only compile other files.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Even compiled files can be read if someone really wants to, so they aren't really protected

Comment: I konw, I only want to increase difficulty to get source code.

Answer (score 1):

As you acknowledge in the comment, there is a limitation to how much you can protect your source code, and you would be satisfied with simply increasing difficulty.

With the right settings with this [Javascript obfuscator](https://obfuscator.io/), you can make your code much harder to reverse engineer. To only obfuscate only parts of the project, be sure to use "Identifiers Prefix" and NOT to use "Rename Globals"